# How can I add navigation in the navigation header?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to create a button for navigating to "CreateScreen", the button is placed in the header so I wrote it inside  `<NavigationContainer>` as the documentation suggested, but it seems I don't have access to navigation, **I don't actually need it inside NavigationContainer**, so if you have other suggestions for implementing(for example, implementing the button inside the component) it will be great.

That's What I'm trying to accomplish(part of app.js)

```
headerRight: () => {
            return <TouchableOpacity>
              <Feather name="plus" size={30} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Create')} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
```

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Index">
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Index"
          component={IndexScreen}
          options={{
            title: 'Home',
            headerRight: () => {
              return (
                <TouchableOpacity>
                  <Feather
                    name="plus"
                    size={30}
                    onPress={
                      () => navigation.navigate('Create')
                      //Thats what Im trying to accomplish
                    }
                  />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              );
            },
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="Show" component={ShowScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Create" component={CreateScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In option will return navigation

```
function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Index">
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Index"
          component={IndexScreen}
          //navigation<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<here
          options={({navigation, route}) => ({
            title: 'Home',
            headerRight: () => {
              return (
                <TouchableOpacity>
                  <Feather
                    name="plus"
                    size={30}
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Create')}
                  />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              );
            },
          })}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="Show" component={ShowScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Create" component={CreateScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes, If you asking for the upvote, I tried to upvote you but I seems I dont have enough rep

Comment: Accept the question is you check to check the stick if my answer is right. It is below button upvote and downvote. This link is a tour of StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @Ahn Devit in your code it seems that 'options' receives a function, you write it as `({navigation, route}) => ({` after the `=>` why do you open a bracket before the curly bracket? I couldn't figure out this syntax

Comment: ({navigation, route}) => ({})  equal with ({navigation, route}) => {return({})}

Answer (score 1):

you can use the useNavigation hook to gain access to the navigation prop:

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

const navigation = useNavigation();
navigation.goBack();
```

source:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/

Comment: It actually did not work for me, it gave me an error about violating hooks rules, but my problem had been fixed already, thank you anyway.